# Sequelizejs model create callback is not running synchronously?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, synchronous, sequelize.js

I'm using [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/) and [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) in my [node.js](http://nodejs.org) application. I have two tables with one-to-one relationship - `Customers` and `Users`.

There is foreign key `UserId` in the `Customers` table. So, I firstly insert into the `Users` table and **then** insert into the `Customers` with the last inserted `UserId`. Here is my controller code:

```js
var self = this;

async.each(data, function(row, callback) {
    var userData = {
        name: row.name,
        /** **/
    }
    // self.User is User model
    self.User.create(userData).then(function(user) {
      console.log("[User.create] succeeded");
      /** **/
      // self.Model is Customer model
      self.Model.create(cusData).then(function(customer) {
          console.log("[Customer.create] succeeded");
          /** **/
      }).catch(function(err) {
          throw err;
      }); // EOL self.Model.create
    }).catch(function(err) {
          throw err;
    }); // EOL self.User.create
    callback();
}, function(err){
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

I'm using [async.each()](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) to loop the array of 2 records synchronously. When I inserted the two records, the console output is:

```
[User.create] succeeded
[User.create] succeeded
[Customer.create] succeeded
[Customer.create] succeeded
```

What I expected is:

```
[User.create] succeeded
[Customer.create] succeeded
[User.create] succeeded    
[Customer.create] succeeded
```

I think it could be a problem of synchronous flow in asynchronous programming. What am I wrong? I think I'm using the callbacks correctly.

Comment: How did you insert two records? You might be calling that twice in sequence, which starts two inserts before the callbacks have the opportunity to fire. If you want the full inserts done in sequence, you need to begin the second one in the first's last callback.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Ah...I use a node module [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) to loop the records. I updated the code in my question.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy likely to be the mis-placed call of `callback()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initiating the two inserts asynchronously, so you've no guarantee on the order of the follow-up queries. For all you know, depending on locks, you could get the current or your expected result.

To force the order, move the iteration forward from *within* the inner callback:

```
  self.Model.create(cusData).then(function(customer) {
      console.log("[Customer.create] succeeded");
      /** move the iterator forward here, using e.g. recursion **/
  })
```

Comment: The iterator forward means `callback()`?

Comment: No, I mean that you need to use a proper iterator or something that amounts to one, which can yield as needed, or locks as needed, or be advanced step by step, e.g. `iter = function(cb, arr, idx) { cb(arr, idx); /* which takes care of calling iter(arr, idx + 1); */ }; ` or whatever is that is more appropriate and actually valid. Your current code basically contains a logic error if you wish to force the order.

Comment: Alternatively, don't use the `each.async` method, plain and simple, and reorganize your code accordingly.

Comment: [async.whilst()](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst) did solve my problem. Thank you. don't know why `async.each()` not work.